# Not so expensive but decent motherboard for amd 5600G APU

Tags: motherboard, pc

Some online video recommended motherboards like:

*Asus TUF Gaming B550M-Plus (Wi-Fi) Motherboard*

*MSI MAG B550M Mortar Gaming Motherboard, Micro-ATX*

But they look little to extra expensive for me and also it's probably expensive because it has a 1200 audio codec and maybe some other features.

So I'm not sure if I really need that codec or some entry level codecs like ALC887/897 would be decent enough for me.

Basically, I can't afford anything new to upgrade this PC I'm about to build. I won't upgrade it with GPU or a new CPU/GPU at least for 2 years.

I mean I need decent performance from this APU *at present*.

---

I mean I need something which is decent enough and not so expensive which works quite good for 5600G.

If it has built in Wi-Fi, that would be good but I can use external Wi Fi if you think I can have a better deal with non Wi-Fi motherboard.

---

**My main tasks on this PC would be:**

1. Gaming at medium settings especially that were released a few years ago (I *don't* plan to play current high graphics games like COD Warzone or RDR2)
2. Listening to some music while I'm working
3. Watching movies online (I'm not movie addict. Just casual movies watch)
4. Watching YouTube videos

Note: I have a lot of suggestions already which are within my budget but some people say ALC 887/897 isn't good audio you might get bad experience or hissy sound or interreference with other components of PC (*which honestly I don't even understand what it means and how it happens*).

*At the same time, I'm seeing a lot people buying those motherboards (with ALC 887/897 or 892/897) on Amazon in India.*

So I'm really confused. I can't make a decision.

Note: I have a Dell Inspiron laptop and I never noticed any audio problem in that. I'm not sure if ALC 887/897 is even worst than that. ([Here are some more details about that in case you want to see](https://superuser.com/questions/1709689/how-do-i-find-out-what-audio-device-codec-my-laptop-have)).

Note 2: I will use 2x8GB 3200 Mhz RAMs only. And I won't overclock anything in my PC.

**Given all that, please recommend motherboard(s) that should work decent enough for 5600G APU and a decent audio.**

Answer (score 0):

The Gigabyte B550 Gaming X V2 is probably what you are looking for. There is a problem with your CPU that it doesn't support much motherboards out of the box, but since this one has BIOS flashback, that won't be an issue for you. The audio is basic, but good enough (I know, ALC887, but that is still good enough for your use case). It has good enough VRM to not throttle your cpu, and supports dual monitor on the APU. It does not have wifi and is a little low on USB ports on the back, but minor details (I need 6 for my youtubing, you probably don't)